# multi level module with lazy loading is not working

Tags: angular, module, routes, lazy-loading, angular-routing

I have this multi level module with each routing module, but only the first routing module is working, the second module is not.

Each module is lazy loading, with default path is aim to the first module.

**app.module**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CoreModule,
    SharedModule,
    FeaturesModule,

    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', loadChildren: './features/features.module#FeaturesModule'}
    ]),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

**features.module**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CoreModule,
    FeaturesRoutingModule,
    MainModule,
    RegisterModule
  ]
})

//routing
const routes: Routes = [
 { path: '', loadChildren: './main/main.module#MainModule' },
 { path: NAVIGATIONS.REGISTER, loadChildren: './register/register.module#RegisterModule' },
 ];
```

**main.module**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CoreModule,
    SharedModule,
    MainRoutingModule,
    MainFeaturesModule
  ],
 /..../})

// routing
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: MainPageComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: LandingPageComponent },
      /..../
      { path: NAVIGATIONS.EXPLORE, loadChildren: './main-features/explore/explore.module#ExploreModule'},
      { path: '**', component: NotfoundPageComponent }
    ]
  }
];
```

**register.module**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CoreModule,
    SharedModule,
    RegisterRoutingModule
  ],
  /.../})

// routing
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: RegisterPageComponent }
];
```

**Hierarchy**

```
app.module
  |
  L features.module // lazy load default
       |
       L main.module // lazy load default
       |
       L register.module
```

the main module routing is working just fine, but the register module is not, there is no error or anything, but anything I put in the register module routing AND the features module routing is not working and always get to 'Page Not Found' component which I declared in main module routing.

the reason why I put main module and register module separate is because the main module have this header and footer which I don't want to show in register, then the 'Page Not Found' can get the header and footer.

how to tackle this issue with still having multi level module routing?

Comment: Can you share `NAVIGATIONS` constants?

Comment: There is no sense in importing them, totally defeats the concept of `lazyloading`. if you use [augury](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/augury/elgalmkoelokbchhkhacckoklkejnhcd?hl=en) extension you would even notice a duplication in your routes!! refer to the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules)

Answer (score 6):

When you want to lazy load some modules in your angular applications, NEVER EVER import them anywhere.

In your app module, you are importing `FeaturesModule` which breaks the lazy loading. So, delete `FeaturesModule` import from `app.module.ts` Likewise, you should delete `MainModule`, `RegisterModule` from `features.module.ts`

What this does is that redefine `path: ''` multiple times.

I, also, noticed that you are importing `CoreModule` in lazy loaded modules. I assume your `CoreModule` provide some services. Importing a module, which provides services, in a lazy loaded module will result in different instances of services. Lazy loaded modules have their own dependency injection mechanism.

For more information [check the docs](http://MainModule,%20%20%20%20%20RegisterModule)